# How can I Close a popup window, after execute Update SQL. (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a pop-up page. That pop-up window has a radio button, a text box, and an execute button. I want to work that page working like... when pressing the button, run a update SQL with the values of the radio button and text box, and close itself.

I tried that answer in the following link. But the pop-up page just reloaded and the page stayed open. [How to close popup window in Oracle-apex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938451/how-to-close-popup-window-in-oracle-apex)

If possible, I would like to validate the value of the text box. If it was an incorrect value then break the process with a message. If path that validation, run a update SQL and close the pop-up window.

Thank you for your kindness for read this confusing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT RESOLVED IT!
Not use any close method, redirect util is fine work like this `APEX_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL (APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page => 7));`

Thank you to all ppl for look this page :)

Comment: While it probably works, it's not a good practice to do a redirect in a modal dialog as explained here: https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/

Comment: Oh, I've only read about halfway through, but that's a nice page! Thank you for your good point out :D

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a "Close Dialog" process type after your Save Process.

[image: Close Dialog Process]

Make sure that you also set the server side condition accordingly so that the dialog only closes after your save process.

Comment: Hi I made the close dialog process but its not close what to set the server side condition can you add it to the answer please , I need after INSERT complete close the window